# Python, printing two columns of numbers using for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I need some very basic help with Python 3.3. I'm trying to get a better understanding of formatting using a for loop and I want to simply print out the odd numbers from 1-20 in two columns.

Here is what I've tried:

```
for col1 in range(1,10,2):
    for col2 in range(11,20,2):
        print(col1,'\t',col2)
```

For some reason my output is very strange. The left column has the odd numbers from 1-10, but each number is listed five times before it goes to the next number

```
1   11
1   13
1   15
1   17
1   19
3   11
3   13
3   15
3   17
3   19
etc..
```

What i want is:

```
1   11
3   13
5   15
7   17
9   19
```

Comment: Given your code, the output makes sense.  Your question is?

Comment: You nested a for-loop in another for-loop, so for every iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will be iterated from start to end. Thus, the inner loop is used 5 times, leading to the duplicate numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a second for-loop or `zip` here.  Instead, all you need is this:

```
>>> for n in range(1, 10, 2):
...     print(n, '\t', n + 10)
...
1        11
3        13
5        15
7        17
9        19
>>>
```

It works because the numbers in the second column are simply those in the first plus 10.

Answer (score 5):

You should do it using `zip`:

```
for i,j in zip(range(1,10,2), range(11,20,2)):
    print('{}\t{}'.format(i,j))

[OUTPUT]
1   11
3   13
5   15
7   17
9   19
```

When you use nested loops, the problem is that you are printing the second column for *each* number in the first column, which is not what you want. Instead, you want to iterate through them simultaneously. That is where `zip` comes in handy.